# Doing tasks in order Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, synchronization, queue

I have been reading several topics concerning this issue but somehow it seems not to work for me, it's a 'simple' thing but somehow it does not work it in the right order.

I am retrieving data from Firebase into a dictionary(EmployeesData) which already has data when the view is loaded.(send through the segue) In the TableViewController I want the Dictionary data to be put into an object(struct), so I do a for loop which loads the objects in 'Result'. But somehow if the tableview loads it's data, 'Result.Employees' is empty. So I read about the queues, tried some solutions but all resulted in the same -> 'Result == nil'

My question is: why does this not work?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            for x in self.EmployeesData{
                self.Result.Employees?.append( Employee(
                    ID: x.value[self.Emp.ID] as? String,
                    FirstName: x.value[self.Emp.FirstName] as? String,
                    LastName: x.value[self.Emp.LastName] as? String,
                    PhoneNumber: x.value[self.Emp.PhoneNumber] as? String,
                    Address: x.value[self.Emp.PhoneNumber] as? String,
                    ZipCode: x.value[self.Emp.ZipCode] as? String,
                    Number: x.value[self.Emp.Number] as? String,
                    City: x.value[self.Emp.City] as? String,
                    DateOfBirth: x.value[self.Emp.DateOfBirth] as? Date,
                    Role: x.value[self.Emp.Role] as? String,
                    Email: x.value[self.Emp.Email] as? String,
                    workDays: nil)
                )
            }

            self.tableView.register(EmployeeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self._View.EmployeeCell)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

EmployeesData is set in the previous controller

```
Database.database().reference()
                    .child(Child.Employees)
                    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let empDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    EmployeesDictionary = empDict
                }
            }) { (error) in
                print(error)
        }
```

I send it with the view by:

```
vc.EmployeesData = self.EmployeesDictionary
```

Comment: where you load data from firebase ? , attach code

Comment: In the previous ViewController, I send it with the segue. EmployeesData contains of results before the for loop starts.

Comment: You need to show how and when `self.EmployeesData` is set and how and when this view controller is created and displayed.

Comment: Assuming I'm reading your braces correctly, your call to `reloadData()` is inside the background queue closure like it should be. One thing that's wrong, though: Th call call to `self.tableView.register()` needs to be done on the main thread. The easy way to fix this would be to put it inside your `DispatchQueue.main.async` call to reload the tableView data.

Comment: You call the tableView register inside the global queue , seems don't specify a data source , call here to global queue is useless as it only loops for the array , it's not  an actual firebase call

Comment: rmaddy: I have added it now, thanks for your reply

Comment: Duncan C: Good point, I tried it but then It somehow can't find the cell anymore, this solution worked for me

Comment: sh_Khan I misread your point, but besides the register call, the for loop does not seem to work but when I call the dictionary it works, is there an extra step possible that it only continues when the for loop is ready?

Comment: @MisterJFK When you reply to someone, precede their username with the `@` symbol otherwise they may not be notified of your message.

Comment: You still need to show the relationship of this code. When and where are each of these bits of code called? Your issue seems to be that your 2nd view controller is loaded before `EmployeesDictionary` is actually populated in the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The code in viewDidLoad is running before vc.EmployeeData is populated.

Move the code in viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear or better yet - make an initializer that you can pass the Dictionary to that also initializes and populates the EmployeeData array.

Also, that code should be almost instantaneous so remove the *DispatchQueue.main.async* as it's probably not needed - that depends on the use case though.